# Naming rows in a 3D array in R

Tags: arrays, r

Hi I had a question about naming rows in a 3D array in R. If I have the following code:

```
x<-rbind(c(46,30),c(21,25),c(50,50))
y<-rbind(c(46,43),c(41,35),c(50,50))
test<-array(data = c(x,y),dim = c(3,2,2))
```

how would I go about giving all of the rows of the test array **different** names. By different I mean I want each row of the array to have a unique name. Say for example, I want the rows in the 'slice' of the array corresponding to test[,,1] to be called 'a','b', and 'c' and I want the rows in the slice of the array corresponding to test[,,2] to be called 'd','e' and 'f'?

I've tried:

```
rownames(test[,,1])<-c('a','b','c')
rownames(test[,,2])<-c('d','e','f')
```

but this doesn't seem to work. The only answers I've found on this website give the same row names for every slice of the array. Thanks.

Comment: I do not believe that is possible.  Look at the help page `?array` and read the section about `dimnames`.  Array simply does not support that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword for naming the dimensions in a 3-dimensional (or higher) array is `dimnames`, but I don't think the thing you are asking for (with the dynamically changing dimension names) is doable.  It sounds like you want to create a list of named arrays instead.  Try

```
l = list(table1 = test[,,1], table2 = test[,,2])
rownames(l[[1]]) <- c('a','b','c')
rownames(l[[2]]) <- c('d','e','f')
```